# Failed to send e-mail

Tags: email

When I send e-mail to an addres, I received this message

Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

```
 osis@smansapati.sch.id
```

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain smansapati.sch.id by aspmx.l.google.com. [2a00:1450:400c:c0a::1a].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 em3si16520736wib.90 - gsmtp

----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;
        bh=pBGyddCs3lPlcKwIsFT91b7wHTDWnoqShCs42YCbVDg=;
        b=SkFhh6R5Nj+XKBJZM+ttms6SVAC+hXCYnoTM3s6NUiAOdYFZMqbuu1NPkg7YHsxOW3
         FRSWSzoQDDxrCOY3RHuyvvyPT1YmJ5c1pjQYOAmEDStVbGjtgBsqAb+G3Si6quzFg57f
         um+WJ2fwUQ/yPw3/PxaJUORM92gEXve7vCFK0Yi5m3OTbyJHwPVmRZUeeK0qpcKmemfM
         69TzYp+1eMZfXAQ+0cX9PAb0ozEJZZerE2oh88Hu2dCvgnhUCsy4QpR2TD3LpCT3bdav
         J9cKlQ61Y6NgQsCp/Esx4uy5b8LK+AKLxlJvsHWDVuPXP0nfuir8UvrqX03VVh+Z507p
         AtKw==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.194.119.161 with SMTP id kv1mr57092557wjb.157.1438036082343;
 Mon, 27 Jul 2015 15:28:02 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.28.146.80 with HTTP; Mon, 27 Jul 2015 15:28:01 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2015 05:28:01 +0700
Message-ID: 
Subject: Proposal Muktamar
From: Nugraha Setyawan 
To: osis@smansapati.sch.id
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=089e01227ba0dd14ba051be2ddc8

Comment: It appears the email does not exist.

Comment: pick up the telephone

Answer (score 1):

The mail account you tried to reach does not exist on the server. That's what the error message tells you. Literally.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the description attached to the 550 numeric error code tells you that the account doesn't exist on the email server to which the message was sent:

```
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist.
```

So you either mistyped the address or, if it was once a valid email address, it no longer is valid, perhaps because the user is no longer using that email service provider.

If you encounter other error codes in the future in bounced email, the numeric error codes have specific meanings, e.g., see [SMTP and ESMTP error code list](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/email-troubleshooting/smtp-and-esmtp-error-code-list).

A [550 email error code](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/bounceback-errors/email-error-550) is returned when "the recipient's mailbox is unavailable due to being incorrectly typed or not found."

> The 550 series of errors are referred to as hard bounces. This means
>   the problem is permanent and attempting to send the message again in
>   the same fashion won't work. For a more in-depth explanation on hard
>   bounces and general email bounceback reasons you can read [why does
>   email bounce, bounceback, or
>   error?](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/email-troubleshooting/email-bounce-bounceback-error)

Often, as in this case where "The email account that you tried to reach does not exist" appears after the error code, the bounced email contains descriptive text with the error code explaining what the error code means.